# Pulldown on optocoupler's input side

Tags: opto-isolator

I saw some schematic that uses optocoupler to make isolation to the MCU digital input pin. Schematic below.

I was wondering why do they need R700 as a pulldown since the LED inside the optocoupler is current controlled (not voltage controlled) and hence isn't sensitive to outside interference?

Is there any scenario where this pulldown would actually have a purpose?

[image]

Comment: I see no reason for R700. The only thing I can think of is that they are trying to make the LED turn off faster to improve bandwidth, but I am pretty sure you can't take this approach if that's what you want.

Comment: Such a parallel resistor can increase the switching threshold, but 100 kΩ does not make sense for that.

Answer (score 2):

Given the resistance ratio of 100:1 which represents about 1000:1 in current (10mA in operating current for the LED vs. 10uA of bleeding leakage, EMI or whatever at the ~1V where an IR LED begins to conduct) it doesn't look particularly useful.

If you're expecting that much crud on the input the LED should have reverse protection and it doesn't.

If they expect the '10V' input line to go right to zero when opened up, then it might have some function, but that would depend on something off the page.